# My entire RSS feed is displaying, unformatted, in email body

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've been trying to follow [the tutorial located here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_to_include_an_rss_feed_in_an_email_message_using_ampscript/), with great success - everything is coming together beautifully, except for one issue!

I have a content area at the very top of my email template, and inside that content area, I have placed this code as instructed in the tutorial's step #2:

```
%%before; httpget; 1 "http://newsletter.blogs.wesleyan.edu/feed/"%%
```

But, when I generate a send preview, ***the entire unformatted feed*** appears in that content area.

Below it, the content from the RSS feed is displaying very nicely exactly as I want it to.  But, I'd like to figure out what to do to make the huge block of unformatted xml at the top of the email disappear.

I've tried to hack it with CSS; I've tried to hide that content area with **display:none;** but that hasn't worked.

Am I missing something obvious that's causing the entire unformatted RSS feed to appear at the top of my email?

Comment: When you say "Content Area", you're using the very specific, ET definition of Content Area, correct?  Meaning, "something that lives in the "My Contents" folder, and you call directly using ContentArea() or ContentAreaByName().  I just want to confirm this before proceeding.

Comment: Yes.  The content area lives in the "My Contents" folder, and I call directly using ContentAreaByName()

Comment: Could you do a SendPreview, and actually send a Test Send to yourself?  What does that email look like?

Comment: Timothy, as I stated in the question, "When I generate a Send Preview, the entire unstyled feed appears in that content area." I didn't realize that including the content area  in the template itself would pull in the entire feed.  I now realize that calling using ContentAreaByName() means that the ContentArea is not included in the email itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your AMPscript block, this is sort of a guess, but I think what may be happening is this:

Your email contains a content area you dropped *directly in the email*.  Which means this block of code `%%before; httpget; 1 "http://newsletter.blogs.wesleyan.edu/feed/"%%` is literally being called inside the email.

Delete that content area from the email, and only reference it with

```
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\path\to\my\feed")
```

The RSS call should live in the content area located here - `my contents\path\to\my\feed)` and not directly in your email.

Make sense?

Comment: He is using ContentAreaByName already.

Comment: I'm suggesting its also in the email directly

Comment: Thank you, that worked!  I did have the ContentArea in the email directly as well as in "My Contents."   I removed the content area that contained the RSS call from the actual email template itself, and this solves the problem.